# adding TableView to AlertController in swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview

[image]

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let row=animals[indexPath.row]
        let cellIdentifier = "memoCell"
        var cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MemoCellTableViewCell

        if cell == nil {
            print("cell is nill")
            cell = MemoCellTableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        }

        cell.name?.text="aaa"
        cell.address?.text="haha"
        return cell
    }
```

I have below error.

'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier memoCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

I don't know why. 
I set class with no error on storyboard and also set identifier correctly

my code is on github
https://github.com/kotran88/iostableviewTest

please help me to get this right

Comment: Did you try to `init` the `UITableViewCell` with `style` and `reuseIdentifier`, there is an initializer already there, just override it and call `super`.

Comment: The title of this question hass nothing to do with the what you put in your question. That's confusing.

Comment: Please don't screenshot your code. Include it as a part of your question, like you did with the second part.

Answer (score 1):

You have to register your your xib/nib in `ViewController` viewDidLoad method

```
    let yourCustomNib = UINib(nibName: "MemoCellTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    self.tableView.register(yourCustomNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "memoCell")
```